# How activate account by mail with token register -MERN-?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

When the user creates an account, he receives by email with a link that has a token at the end. How can I extract that token and then do a get  to activate the account?
Or is there another way to use the registration token to verify the account?

```
function ActivationEmail() {
    const {ActToken} = useParams();
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(ActToken){
            const activationEmail = async () => {
                try { 
                    await axios.get('/api/users/verificare?validation=', {ActToken})
                } catch (err) {
     }
            }
            activationEmail()
        }
    },[ActToken])
```

Route:

```
 <Route path="/verification?t=:ActToken" component={ActivationEmail} />
```

I tried with console.log to see what's happen when i m in this path, my function is not called and console.log(ActToken) is useless....
If i coppy token generate from link and into in my postman .get(/api/users/verificare?validation='here into token from email') it's working, account is verified.
Mail recive looking like:

```
http://localhost:3000/verification?t=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI2MDlmOTYzZWQ2ZmUxMjNlOTBkZDhkNjIiLCJpYXQiOjE2MjEwNzE0MjIsImV4cCI6MTYyMTEwNzQyMn0.TmeuCgP7PeR2UKx1sDkuYBPr-h5aiDQK-_SyY2nB54g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useParams` hook is used to get the URL params and not for the Query parameters (Query params exists after the `?` character).

Use the following code to get the token.

```
 const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
 const token= queryParams.get('t')
```

Also do some code structure changes as follows

```
const activationEmail = async (token) => {
    try { 
        await axios.get(`/api/users/verificare?validation=${token}`)
    } 
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

function ActivationEmail() {
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const ActToken = queryParams.get('t');

    useEffect(() => {
        if(ActToken){
            activationEmail(ActToken)
        }
    },[])

    // Return your component DOM here
}
```

Also update the route path (we wont need to mention the Query param while defining route path)

```
 <Route path="/verification" component={ActivationEmail} />
```

Comment: I put     const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    const ActToken= queryParams.get('t') in ActivationEmail but it's doesn't work

Comment: Also, i have console log  everywhere for ActToken and it is never displayed

Comment: Try changing your route path to “/verification”. Remove the part ‘t:ActToken’.

Comment: I modify in ->  await axios.get(`/api/users/verificare?validation=${ActToken}`) and it's working now, but when i clicked button from link-> redirect and must to entry in this link  twice(when redirect from mail and after i need to go link-> click him-> enter and now is true)

Comment: I am not able to fully understand what you said in the previous comment. Are you telling 'you need to click the link twice to make it work'?

Comment: I need to reconfirm route from mail with another enter in link for activate, how should i solve this problem? 
And thank you a million times for your help, God bless you

Comment: In the mail I have a button that redirects me to my page. The moment he redirected me, I have to go up to the link and enter that link again to validate the account.

Comment: In email button link you bind the '/verification?t=token' url right?

Comment: Yes, link bind is ok, but i need to go on top-click this link, and press enter for activate account, the activate is not instantly when i pressed button from link, i need press enter in my page on link again for activate them

Comment: Come to chat.stackoverflow.com. In stackoverflow comments we cant continue long conversation

Comment: I think i m user15633282 how can find you?

Comment: My user ID is 4422413

Comment: I think i don t have reputation to make a conversation..... I m user15633282 if u can started....

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232448/frontend-teacher

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq."  i edit now the post and i try to expose problem again.

Comment: I added 3 photo. Press button from link(photo 1) reddirect to page(photo 2) and i need to click on this link from mail and press enter again to validate account(photo 3 state.data.verified from false->true)

Comment: I recive from mail link and i will go in page with him. I need to click link and press enter to validate account. I tried to go in postman, create account and i recive a token. I go in my localhost300:/verification?t= and i enter the token from postman, account was instantly actived, but from mail i need to re-enter link or click link->enter to validate. Sorry for chat, i have 3 reputation and can't talk on chat.stack...

Comment: I solve that problem: in another browe it s working, in chrome have problem.

Comment: Excuse me, sir, but do you know the answer to this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67558652/how-find-user-id-by-token-mern-for-change-password-account